# How to launch Fragment instead of the Activitiy itself?

Tags: android, android-fragments, main-activity

How can i start a `Fragment` in the `AboutAndHelpActivity` instead of the `Activity` itself or how can i put the `Fragment` in `startActivity()`?

```
//if it is the first start of the app, open HelpFragment once.

    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    if (isFirstRun) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutAndHelpActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you want to think about activity and fragment
I will suggest you to read about it
So that you will get idea
Please check the link for fragment information

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

You can add, remove or replace the fragment in the activity
You should manage fragment life cycle.
Otherwise you might get some unexpected UI or app issues

Answer (score 0):

You are completely misunderstand what is Activities and Fragments. Read about them again.

tl;dr: Activity - base unit. Fragment - part. Fragment can be only hosted in some activity, and can't be displayed other way.

Here how you can display fragment in activity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_holder,new MyFragment())
            .addToBackStack(MyFragment.class.getSimpleName())
            .commit();
```

Comment: I know the difference. But i want to start a fragment once the first time the app is started. Not only the activity. How can I do that..

Comment: You have two options: 1) Add fragment to current activity (some startup activity). 2) When you'll start your main activity, add some extra to tell activity to show fragment.

Comment: You can put `Extra` something in `Intent`. Put Boolean "isFirstRun" and in activity do `getIntent()` and `getExtras()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, `AboutAndHelpActivity` is supposed to be started on the app's first run **and** house a Fragment.
If so, the starting the Activity part is already solved in you initial question, so what remains is showing the Fragment. Two options make sense to me:

1. In case `AboutAndHelpActivity`'s only job is to house the Fragment and won't be started for any other purpose, the Fragment can be added to its layout xml.
2. Otherwise, the Fragment needs to be added dynamically based on an Intent extra as already pointed out by @Ekalips.